# Failed to connect to remote Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, remote-server

I have a remote Jupyter Notebook Server on an ubuntu server (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) up and running.
The server uses a self-signed certificate.
Connection to the server is possible via Browser with `https://<servername>:<port>/?token=<token>`
When i use the same URL in VS Code (1.43.2) with MS Python Extension (2020.3.71659) the following error occurs:

`Failed to connect to remote Jupyter notebook.
Check that the Jupyter Server URI setting has a valid running server specified.
https://<servername>:<port>/
Error: Invalid response: 503 Service Unavailable`

Are there any suggested solutions?